# Issues with Dynamic Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Well I asked a question and got like 90% answer , I need to resolve the remaining 10 % of it.

It's basically an Events Page so on the Click over the selected item from a StackView ,it opens another fragment which has in it 2 textViews and 1 imageView ,
All these pages (10+) will be symmetrical so I decided to make it dynamic, so that it's' easy to work upon and handle.

**EventsFragment**

```
   public class EventsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private StackView stackView;
    private ArrayList<Stack_Items> list;
    TypedArray eventLogo;
    String eventName[],eventDesc[];

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        eventLogo = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.event_stack_icon);
        eventName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_stack);
        eventDesc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_desc_stack);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, null);
        stackView = (StackView) view.findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
        list = new ArrayList<Stack_Items>();

        //Adding items to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogo.length(); i++) {
            list.add(new Stack_Items(eventName[i], eventLogo.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }
        //Calling adapter and setting it over stackView
        Stack_Adapter adapter = new Stack_Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
        stackView.setAdapter(adapter);
        stackView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View
                    view, int position, long id) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment eventDescFragment = new DynamicEventsPage().newInstance(R.array.event_stack,R.array.event_desc_stack,eventLogo.getResourceId(position, -1));
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, eventDescFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**DynamicEventPage**

```
public class DynamicEventsPage extends Fragment{
    public static final String BUNDLE_STRING_KEY = "BUNDLE_STRING_KEY";
    public static final String BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY = "BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY";
    public static final String BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY = "BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY";

    public static Fragment newInstance(final int stringId,final int descStringId, final int drawableId) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_STRING_KEY, stringId);
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY, drawableId);
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY,descStringId);
        Fragment fragment = new DynamicEventsPage();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_events_page, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(bundle.getInt(BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(bundle.getInt(BUNDLE_STRING_KEY));
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewdesc)).setText(bundle.getInt(BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY));
    }

}
```

**dynamic_events_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="0.40" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewdesc"
        android:layout_weight="0.40" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="0.40" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Error is get is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0001

E/AndroidRuntime:     at package.DynamicEventsPage.onViewCreated(DynamicEventsPage.java:39)
```

So What is the fix?

Comment: What line is DynamicEventsPage.java:39?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change newInstance to take String instead of int

```
public static Fragment newInstance(final String eventName,final String eventDescr, final int drawableId) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_KEY, stringId);
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY, drawableId);
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY,descStringId);
        Fragment fragment = new DynamicEventsPage();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
}
```

and onViewCreate to read String instead of int

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(bundle.getInt(BUNDLE_DRAWABLE_KEY));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_STRING_KEY));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewdesc)).setText(bundle.getString(BUNDLE_STRING_DESC_KEY));
}
```

in onItemClick change

```
Fragment eventDescFragment = new DynamicEventsPage().newInstance(R.array.event_stack,R.array.event_desc_stack,eventLogo.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

with

```
String name = (position < eventName.length) ? eventName[position] : "";
String description = (position < eventDesc.length) ? eventDesc[position] : "";
Fragment eventDescFragment = DynamicEventsPage.newInstance(eventName, description,eventLogo.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

Comment: You're like a genius man .:3 ..can i have your email ? Please .

Answer (score 1):

The error message is showing

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0001

It means you are trying to refer to some string variable which is not there in strings.xml file.

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the text of an image view to an array of strings `R.array.somearray` and that's wrong. You should assign it to a String resource `R.string.somestring`.

Some else which is wrong in your Fragment initialization. It should be

```
Fragment eventDescFragment = DynamicEventsPage.newInstance(R.string.event_stack,R.string.event_desc_stack,eventLogo.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

The way you have it is just initializing a new Fragment and leave it and then initialize a new one on the static `newInstance` method.